# php filling in selected in a dynamic list

Tags: php, checkbox

My question extends on the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544770/showing-selected-values-on-a-multiselect-box) and I couldn't find what I'm looking for posted otherwise.

How do I auto select (checked) options in a checkbox list when the options are being pulled from a mySQL table (dynamic)?

Here's what I have so far:

Pulling the committees (comms) from the table:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comm)){
    foreach ($row as $v){
        $comms[] = $v;
        }
}
```

outputting pretty HTML with tidy PHP (the part I need help with):

```
    foreach ($comms as $comm){
       ?????????
    }
```

How can I output something like?:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="committee" value="blue" checked="checked" />blue<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="committee" value="green"  />green<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="committee" value="orange"  />orange<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="committee" value="purple" checked="checked" />purple<br />
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: How do you identify which items are checked? Is there a flag in each row you're pulling?

Comment: if the value in the html input field matches what's being pulled from the database, then it should be checked.

Comment: How are you displaying the inputs as of now? Just manually outputting them? Or is there an array that you loop through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your colors are stored in an array and your data comes back as an array (likely not the case if you're using `mysql_*` functions), you can print out each checkbox, then compare its value to see if it's in the list of "checked" colors:

```
<?php
$colors = array('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple');

$data = array('blue', 'purple');//array pulled from database.

foreach($colors as $color): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="committee" value="<?= $color ?>" <?= in_array($color, $data) ? 'checked="checked" ' : '' ?>/><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

By the way, you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to check. If someone's tried to submit the form already, then their responses will be in `$_REQUEST` (and `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depend on your form's submission method); you can then write each line as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="committee[]" value="green" <?php if ($_REQUEST['committee'] == 'green') { echo "checked"; } ?> />green<br />
```

If it's coming from the database, you can check in `$comms`"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="committee[]" value="green" <?php if (in_array($comms, 'green') { echo "checked"; } ?> />green<br />
```

You can make the code more efficient by working out in advance whether it's a re-submission or not, and populating a single array with the result from the right place:

```
<?php

if ([form is submitted]) {
    $comms = $_REQUEST["committee"];
} else {
    $comms = getCommsFromDatabase();
}

?>
```

That also gives you the chance to sanitise the input from $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comm)){
    foreach ($row as $v){
        $comms = $v;
        }
}
```

where you can print values from assuming that $v has an attribute Checked

```
   foreach($coms as $key => $value)
   {
      $checked = "";
      $color = $value['color'];
      if($value['checked'] == 'checked')
      $checked = "checked = 'checked'";
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='committee' value='$color' $checked />$color<br />";
```

}